# Laravel redirect back does not work on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple validation, when an exception is raised on the local machine, everything works properly and the page shows errors.

On shared hosting redirect()->back() instead of leaving me on the same page and displaying errors it sends me to the initial route "/".

```
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    };
```

Please help.

UPDATE:

[See the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyuX4.jpg)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
     Options -MultiViews -Indexes
   </IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On

   # Handle Authorization Header
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
   RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

   # Send Requests To Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what is the version of laravel and the version of the PHP on your server?

Comment: @EmekaOkafor Laravel 8 and PHP 8.0 on server

Comment: Ok, is the .htaccess file on same level with your index.php?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same folder (public_html)

Comment: @EmekaOkafor I added .httaccess and a folder image to look at.

Comment: the fallback for 'returning back (previous)' is to redirect to '/' ... so it may not be able to determine the referrer

Comment: I have had this problem for a long time and the only thing that works in this case is: redirect(Session::previousUrl())->withErrors($validator)->withInput(); So this is the only thing that works: **Session::previousUrl()**